# Android HTML WebView

Tags: android, html, webview

I am creating an application and I am trying to load a HTML page in a web view.

I am using the code

```
        WebView webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);
        webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");
```

but continue to receive an error that the web page at file:///android_asset/index.html might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.

Any help would be great

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from assets folder

```
webview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/file.html");
```

from specific folder

```
webview.loadUrl("file:///data/data/com.example.example/files/file.html");
```